# What does $C_n(X)$ in a simplicial complex really mean?

Tags: algebraic-topology

My Algebraic Topology textbook says:

> Let $X$ be a simplicial complex. The group $C_n(X)$ of oriented $n$-chains of $X$ is the free abelian group generated by the oriented $n$-simplexes of $X$.

For example, an element of $C_2(S)$ would be $9P_2P_3P_4-4P_1P_3P_4-5P_1P_2P_3$.

What does $9P_2P_3P_4-4P_1P_3P_4-5P_1P_2P_3$ even mean?? What does it mean to multiply a 2-simplex with a scalar? Do we expand the area of the simplex by $9$ times? Is area even defined in a simplicial complex?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you understand the phrase "free abelian group generated by ..."?

Comment: Sorry for this embarrasingly stupid question. I completely forgot about the "freely abelian group" part, and got caught up with this notion of "scalars in simplical complexes". :D

Answer (score 4):

When they write $5\cdot S$ where $S$ is a simplex they do **not** mean to actually *do* anything with the simplex $S$, it is just a formal expression with which you can calculate.

$S$ becomes nothing but an abstract symbol for symbolic calculation. So $5\cdot S+3\cdot S=8\cdot S$, for example. This is **not** a way of writing, $5$ times the area of $S$ plus $3$ times the area of $S$ is $8$ times the area of $S$. Instead, it just means $5$ times of an object called $S$ plus $3$ times an object called $S$ makes $8$ times an object called $S$.

Given *any* set whatsoever, you can form a free abelian group on it just looking at formal linear combinations of its elements.

*Example:*

Suppose your set of simplices is $X=\{A,B,C\}$. Then the free abelian group over $X$ is the *set* given by all the linear combinations

$$x_1A+x_2B+x_3C$$

The $+$'s in this expression do **not** mean any transformation to be done with the simplices. Imagine the $A,B,C$ being the basis of a vector space of dimension $3$. You can just as well write the vector $x_1A+x_2B+x_3C$ in the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.

Now you make this into a group by saying that addition is defined *componentwise*:

$$(x_1A\color{red}{+}x_2B\color{red}{+}x_3C)\color{red}{+}(y_1A\color{red}{+}y_2B\color{red}{+}y_3C):=(x_1+y_1)A\color{red}{+}(x_2+y_2)B\color{red}{+}(x_3+y_3)C$$

This makes the set of these combinations into an abelian group. To avoid confusion, I drew the $+$'s between elements of the free group in red and the $+$'s of integers in black.

Entirely equivalently, if we had decided to denote the elements of our free abelian group as $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ instead, the definition of addition would look like

$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)+(y_1,y_2,y_3)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2,x_3+y_3)$$

We can connect these notations by *defining* $A:=(1,0,0)$, $B:=(0,1,0)$ and $C:=(0,0,1)$. Indeed, then

$$x_1A+x_2B+x_3C=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$$

So whenever we make the free abelian group over a set with $k$ elements, say, then that means we are taking all the $k$-tuples of integers with componentwise addition. Naturally this also works with infinitely large sets, but then we consider only *finite* linear combinations.

As always in algebra, what matters is not how you name your elements or where they come from, the point is only *what you do with them*. The structure of the algebraic operations is important and nothing else.